# retrieve two database table values in a single html table

Tags: html

I have a table(webmeasurementsuite) in my database(probe_config).I have written an php coding to retrieve the datas from the database and display it in the html table.Can anyone correct my errors please.when I load the php page to the browser,I am getting a blank page.

`<?php`
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","mysql");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM webmeasurementsuite");

echo "`<table border='1'>`

`<tr>`
`<th>`replication`</th>`
     `<th>`wait`</th>`
     `<th>`timeout`</th>`
     `<th>`clearcache`</th>`
     `<th>`name`</th>`
     `<th>`wms`</th>`
`</tr>`;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "`<tr>`";
  echo "`<td>`" . $row['replication'] . "`</td>`";
  echo "`<td>`" . $row['wait'] . "`</td>`";
  echo "`<td>`" . $row['timeout'] . "`</td>`";
  echo "`<td>`" . $row['clearcache'] . "`</td>`";
  echo "`<td>`" . $row['name'] . "`</td>`";
  echo "`<td>`" . $row['wms'] . "`</td>`";
  echo "`</tr`>";
  }
echo "`</table>`";

mysql_close($con);
?>

Comment: You need to be more precise. Please make it easier to help you. Paste your code here and specifically tell us the problem you are facing. Otherwise it will be closed as 'not a question'

Comment: If there is anythingelse else required to answer this question,pls do let me know

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to learn more about [Web Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_development).

[HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) is used only for rendering the information in an appropriate format. For accessing the database records, we got to use server side [Scripting Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language) or Web Technologies([J2EE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J2ee), [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages), [ASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages), and more) to access the database. That one can not be done with HTML alone.

If am wrong, please brief your question bit more.